# RewriteMap prg between Apache threads

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In Apache docs it says that the program (prg) is started when the server is started and with the while loop inside that program, it never exits.

Let's say my program is a PHP script that, on start up, creates a sqlite database in memory and fills up around 200mb of memory. When the apache is ran and split into threads, is this PHP script ran on all of those, giving all threads +200mb or is it just ran on a single instance?

Thanks

Comment: Your PHP script will be executed on worker (thread) once matching HTTP request is processed. Only once (for single request). If it will be thread or worker process depends on MPM configuration.

Comment: We are using prefork mpm